# Sugar Free Syntax

Tags: code-golf, string, syntax, haskell

In Haskell the list notation:

```
[a,b,c]
```

Is just syntactic sugar for:

```
a:b:c:[]
```

And the string notation:

```
"abc"
```

Is just syntactic sugar for:

```
['a','b','c']
```

This means that the string:

```
"abc"
```

Is the same as:

```
'a':'b':'c':[]
```

## Task

Given a string you should output what the de-syntaxed version would look like in Haskell.

## Rules

- You will receive a string by any valid input method, you should output a string ending with `:[]` with every character from the input surrounded by `'` and separated by `:`.  The empty string should output `[]`.
- You can assume that you will not receive any characters that require escaping (e.g. `'`, newlines, tabs ...) and that input will be in the printable ascii range
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) you should aim to minimize the byte count of your answer

### Test Cases

```
"" -> []
"a" -> 'a':[]
"Hello, World" -> 'H':'e':'l':'l':'o':',':' ':'W':'o':'r':'l':'d':[]
```

Comment: Will the input ever have non-ascii values? Your restriction on characters that require escaping either requires we know which characters Haskell will escape or assumes your list is exhaustive.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman You can assume they are in the ascii range

Comment: Does the string come in surrounded by `"`?  Or is that just to signify that it's a string?

Comment: @nmjcman101 Just there to indicate its a string (hard to represent the empty string otherwise).

Comment: Is `'a':'':[]` an acceptable output for `a` and `'':[]` an acceptable output for an empty string?

Comment: @totallyhuman Those are not even valid Haskell.  If they were maybe, but nice they are not, definitely no.

Comment: printable ascii?

Comment: @Titus Yes, I'm pretty sure all of the unprintable ascii needs to be escaped.  Anything that has to be escaped in Haskell doesn't need to be suported.

Comment: You should probably specify (printable) ASCII explicitly in the question, as there are a lot of higher Unicode characters that don't need escaping. The rules are somewhat weird and based on Unicode character classes. (The exceptions are just enough spread around to make compression with string literals awkward.)

Comment: This question can be alternatively titled "Diet Haskell".

Comment: May we use `"` instead of `'` (e.g. `"a" -> "a":[]`)?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing No,  `"` and `'` are syntactically different.

Answer (score 89):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 26 bytes

```hs
(++"[]").((++":").show=<<)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyflfrftfQ1tbKTpWSVNPA8SyAjKKM/LLbW1sNP/r1nLlJmbmKdgqZOaVpBYlJpcoqCjgUZ@YlAwA)

**Explanation:**

In non-pointfree notation and using `concatMap` instead of `=<<`, this becomes

```hs
f s = concatMap(\c-> show c ++ ":")s ++ "[]"
```

Given a string `s`, we map each char `c` to a string `"'c':"` using the `show` function which returns a string representation of most Haskell types. Those strings are concatenated and a final `[]` is appended.

Although not requested by the challenge, this answer even works with proper escaping, because `show` takes care of it: `f "'"` yields `"'\\'':[]"`.

Comment: Wait a minute, you mean `(++'[':']':[]).((++':':[]).show=<<)`, no?

Comment: When any challenge has a Haskell answer, I upvote it out of principle.  That goes double for this one.

Answer (score 46):

### Haskell, <s>33</s> <s>28</s> 26 bytes

```
foldr((.(':':)).shows)"[]"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P802LT8npUhDQ09D3UrdSlNTrzgjv7xYUyk6Vul/bmJmnoKtQko@l4JCQWlJcEmRT56CikKagpIHUHO@EoZwIqaQ0n8A)

`fold` the given pointfree function from the right into the input string starting with `[]`. The function is: show char as a Haskell char, i.e. surrounded with `'` and concatenate with the result so far after putting a `:` in front of it.

Edit: @Ørjan Johansen saved two bytes. Thanks!

Comment: I suppose that means `(++'[':']':[]).(>>= \c->'\'':[]++[c]++'\'':':':[])`.

Comment: I think this is superior to the other Haskell answer (at the same byte count) due to using `:` to build the list rather than `++`, though both have their own elegance.

Comment: This is rather amazing. Two separate approaches that have the same byte count in the same language.

Answer (score 20):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 32 bytes

```python
lambda s:"%r:"*len(s)%(*s,)+"[]"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYSkm1yEpJKyc1T6NYU1VDq1hHU1spOlbpf3lGZk6qgqEVl0JBUWZeiUaaRmZeQWmJhqam5n@uRC6P1JycfB2F8PyinBQA)

Answer (score 19):

### JavaScript ES6, <s>42</s> <s>40</s> 31 bytes

```
s=>s.replace(/./g,"'$&':")+"[]"
```

Replaces each char with `'<char>':`, then adds `[]` to the end

[Try it online!](https://vihan.org/p/tio/?l=javascript-node&p=K0ssUki0VSi2tSvWK0otyElMTtXQ19NP11FSV1FTt1LS1FaKjlXi4krOzyvOz0nVy8lP10jUUPJIzcnJ11EIzy/KSVFU0tREl0/EIgYU@g8A)

Comment: I love this about CodeGolf. Never knew about `$&`.

Answer (score 17):

## Common Lisp, <s>50</s> 42 bytes

```
(format t"~{'~a':~}[]"(coerce(read)'list))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74/18jLb8oN7FEoUSprlq9LlHdqq42OlZJIzk/tSg5VaMoNTFFUx2oskRT8/9/JY/UnJx8HYXw/KKcFCUA)

Reduced thanks to the comment of @coredump, by using `read` instead of defining a function.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Lisp! Welcome indeed :)

Comment: @Renzo Hi Renzo, you could shrink it a little by using an anonymous lambda form, or simply calling read : `(format t"~{'~a':~}[]"(coerce(read)'list))` (some other questions are stricter w.r.t. inputs and outputs, but here this is fine)

Comment: @coredump, thanks!, I've updated the code.

Answer (score 12):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 11 bytes

```
Í./'&':
A[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v//3Cvnr66mroVl2N07P//iUnJKakA)

Uses a regex to surround every input character with `'':` and then `A`ppends `[]` to the end.

Answer (score 11):

## C, <s>55</s> <s>54</s> 53 bytes

```c
s(char*h){while(*h)printf("'%c':",*h++);puts("[]");}
```

Comment: you can remove the space in `char *h`

Comment: You can do `puts("[]");` instead to output with a trailing newline to save some bytes.

Comment: recursive `s(char*h){*h?printf("'%c':",*h++),s(h):puts("[]");}`

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>15 12 11</s> 10 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to carusocomputing
-1 byte thanks to Adnan
-1 byte thanks to Erik the Outgolfer's genius idea

```
ʒ"'ÿ':"?},
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9W@f/UJCX1w/vVrZTsa3X@/49WV9dRTwRij9ScnHwdhfD8opwU9VgA)

```
ʒ          # Filter out every character that the following code doesn't return 1 for
 "'ÿ':"?   #   Print the string 'ÿ': with ÿ replaced by this character
        }  # End for
         , # No character returned 1 so an empty array is left on the stack. Print that
```

Comment: Apparently I beat you by 4 seconds ;-)

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Yours popped up as I was pressing Post Your Answer.

Comment: You can print the global array instead of pushing the brackets with 3 bytes. You can also interpolate the string for another byte savings for a total of -3, final result 12-bytes: `vy"'ÿ':"?}¯?`

Comment: @carusocomputing I use the string interpolator all the time for test suites, but forget to use it in actual code. Thanks!

Comment: @carusocomputing I thought `vy"'ÿ':"}¯J` would work for 11, but `J` joins the global array, not the whole stack in that situation.

Answer (score 9):

## Pyth, <s>14</s> <s>10</s> 8 bytes

```
j\:a`MQY
```

[Try this!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j%5C%3Aa%60MQY&input=%22%22&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22%22%0A%22a%22%0A%22abcd%22&debug=0)

*-2 bytes thanks to @isaacg*

Finally, pyth is good at something.

#### explanation

```
j\:a`MQY
    `MQ        # map the representation over the input string: ["'a'","'b'",...]
   a   Y       # append the empty list
j\:            # join on :
```

Comment: @isaacg Thank you! I forgot about `M` and I don't know why I didn't use `a`. Now we're at least 2 bytes shorter than all the other solutions here!

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>41</s> <s>38</s> 36 bytes

<sup>-2 bytes thanks to ovs</sup>

```python
print(*map(repr,input()),[],sep=':')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQys3sUCjKLWgSCczr6C0RENTUyc6Vqc4tcBW3Upd8/9/j9ScnHwdhfD8opwUAA)

Comment: Whoops... Forgot that `*map` exists...

Comment: I was puzzled by the empty `input()` for the past 20 minutes (literally), when it could just be a lambda @.@

Comment: [Empty input does work?](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQys3sUCjKLWgSCczr6C0RENTU0cpOlZJpzi1wFbdSl3z/38uAA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @WheatWizard oh, I was using a empty-empty (no newline) input

Comment: You can replace `"[]"` with `[]`

Answer (score 9):

## R, 51 bytes

```
f<-function(x)(paste0(gsub("(.)","'\\1':",x),'[]'))
```

Comment: Nice solution! A few ways you can save some bytes and really get this down. 
[default I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447) lets you just return an anonymous function, or even take input from stdin, the latter of which would be much shorter using `scan(,'')` instead of a function.

Comment: Thanks, am a bit of a newb with R (and code golf!) so haven't quite grasped anonymous functions in it yet, although I was trying to do it without 'function' in there. scan could be useful!

Comment: ah, well an anonymous function is just one where you don't assign it to a variable so you'd just drop the `f<-` from the beginning of your code

Comment: paste0(gsub('(.)',"'\\1':",scan(,"")),'[]')  is 43

Answer (score 8):

## Retina, 12

- 3 bytes saved thanks to @FryAmTheEggman

```
.
'$&':
$
[]
```

2 stages:

- for each remaining character put `'` `':` around it
- add `[]` to the end

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX49LXUVN3YpLhSs69v9/rkSuxKRkLo/UnJx8HYXw/KKcFAA@UU5KUoA).

Comment: Helped the guy you beat by 4 seconds tie you ;).

Comment: I was thinking of this!

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>48</s> <s>46</s> <s>44</s> 37 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to Rod. -7 bytes thanks to Wheat Wizard.*

```python
lambda s:':'.join(map(repr,s)+['[]'])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHYSt1KXS8rPzNPIzexQKMotaBIp1hTO1o9OlY9VvN/QVFmXolCmoa6uiYXnJ2IzPFIzcnJ11EIzy/KSVHX/A8A)

Comment: [Slightly shorter](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHYSt1KXS8rPzNPIzexQKMotaBIp1hTO1o9OlY9VvN/QVFmXolCmoa6uiYXnJ2IzPFIzcnJ11EIzy/KSVHX/A8A)

Comment: One shorter as `lambda s:':'.join(map(repr,[*s,[]]))` or `lambda s:':'.join(map(repr,s))+":[]"`.

Comment: @xnor The second example you give doesn't seem to work for the empty case.  (the original answer looked very similar to that but paid a lot to cover the empty string case)

Answer (score 7):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 19 bytes

```
{S:g|.|'$/':|~'[]'}
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>11 10</s>  8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 byte thanks to Christian (remove concatenation `;` and utilise implicit printing instead)

+0 bytes (fixed for edge case of an empty string - previously the full program: `ŒṘ€j”:“:[]`)

-2 thanks to Erik the Outgolfer (use `p` in place of `;€` since `”:` is effectively length 1; use `Ø[` since it has become shorthand for `⁾[]`)

```
ŒṘ€p”:Ø[
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc7ZzxqWlPwqGGu1eEZ0f///1fyAErl6yiE5xflpCgqAQA)**

A full program printing the result (as a link it returns a list of lists of characters).

...but is there a way to save using STDIN?

#### How?

```
ŒṘ€p”:Ø[ - Main link: list of characters, s  e.g. "Hey"
ŒṘ€      - Python representation for €ach    [["'",'H',"'"],["'",'e',"'"],["'",'y',"'"]]
    ”:   - literal character = ':'
   p     - Cartesian product                 [["'",'H',"'",':'],["'",'e',"'",':'],["'",'y',"'",':']]
         - implicit print (no newline): 'H':'e':'y':
      Ø[ - literal list of characters        ['[',']']
         - implicit print (no newline): []
```

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 36 bytes

```
s=>s?`'${[...s].join`':'`}':[]`:"[]"
```

---

### Try it

```js
f=
s=>s?`'${[...s].join`':'`}':[]`:"[]"
oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(i.value);o.innerText=f(i.value="abc")
```

```html
<input id=i><pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Befunge](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), <s>29</s> 27 bytes

```
<,,,,\_v#`0:~"'':"
@,,"[]"<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/30YHCGLiy5QTDKzqlNTVrZS4HHR0lKJjlWz@//dIzcnJVwjPL8pJUQQA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 22 bytes

19 bytes of code + `-p` flag.

```perl
s/./'$&':/g;$\="[]"
```

Or, for the same bytecount, `s/./'$&':/g;s/$/[]/`.

Quite straight forward: `s/./'$&':/g` surrounds each characters with quotes and add a `:` after. `$\` is implicitly printed after each print, so setting it to `[]` outputs the final `[]`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r6xYAKQVdAv@F@vr6aurqKlb6adbq8TYKkXHKv3/75Gak5OvoxCeX5STAgA)

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 41 bytes

```php
<?=preg_filter("#.#","'$0':",$argn)."[]";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwJVaVJRfFF@UWpBfVJKZl65R5xrv5x/i6eyqac2lkliUnmer5JGak5OvoxCeX5STomTNZW8H1GpbUJSaHp@WmVOSWqShpKynrKSjpK5ioG6lpAPWpamnFB2rZP3//9e8fN3kxOSMVAA)

Comment: 4 bytes shorter: `for(;~$c=$argn[$i++];)echo"'$c':"?>[]`.

Comment: @user63956 need it not a additional `<?` with which option must it be run? Make an own approach I would say to get upvotes and titus have done something similar in the meantime

Comment: It works with the `-R` flag. Tags can be closed even in constructions like `eval()` and `create_function()`.

Answer (score 4):

## brainfuck, 68 bytes

```
+[-->+[<]>-]>>,[<.>.<.>>-[>+<+++++++++]>+.[-]<<,]-[+[+<]>>+]<+++.++.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYo7CoBADESvovVscoIwtTewCCn8gri4IHj@dS0c3qvezPd0XPuznLXCRQi3oASZ3JTapDhh@BeEuoRZCnE42p2Ir2uj1mHLuaRuLHde@xc)

Comment: Doesn't quite work with the empty string - returned me two non-valid characters in your online test. Very nice, otherwise.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll I can't seem to replicate that; With no input I get no output. Could you provide an updated link with that input?

Comment: [This is what I got when I run it](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJ9pOO1oXAuy0tbVtYoGkno2Nnp2dnm40QkzPTifWRlsbWQSo7v9/AA): . With an empty input, it should be returning "[]" without the quotes.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll Your link goes to the "hello world" input (get an updated link by pressing that link/chain button), but yes, I get what you mean. I'll look into that

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll There you go, I fixed it ;)

Answer (score 4):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <del>86</del> <del>83</del> 76 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to @KevinCruijssen*
*-7 bytes thanks to @FlorianSchaetz*

```java
s->{String b="";for(char c:s.toCharArray()){b+="'"+c+"':";};return b+"[]";};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY0xb4MwEIXn8CtOXmKLxD8glEhVpapLpwwdogyHgcTUsS37iIQQv506hT1vee/efbrr8IF75xvb1b@z7yujFSiDMcI3agtjBklrHwkp2cPpGu5py08UtL2eL4DhGkWCN106J3vSRra9VaSdlZ9reFvoHSx@hBZKmOP@OC4FVCVjResCVzcMoA5RkvtI8T0EHLgQY5WXbMtylbPtgRVTERrqg4UqZ@fLc55hVZFtTkOk5i5dT9Kn62QsbyV6bwbOmBAvCHyNfDXGuB38uGDqf/r5eMqm@Q8)

Comment: You can drop 4 bytes. The trailing `;` doesn't have to be counted for lambda answers, the `;` after the `}` isn't necessary at all, and the `{` and `}` can be removed around the for-loop. And you could save 4 more bytes in Java 10 changing both the `String` and `char` to `var`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>135</s>, 131 bytes

```
{({}<>)<>}(((((((()()()()()){})){}{}())){}{})[()()])<>{<>(((((((()()()){}()){}){}()){})[(((()()()){})){}{}()])<>)({}<({}<>)>)<>}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/v1qjutbGTtPGrlYDCjRhULO6FoSra4FMMK0ZDRKOBSqutrFDUa4JVgRUAaOjkaVgpoB0aoLsg9gJttXG7v9/J4R7dJMB)

`+1` byte for the `-c` flag.

Thanks to WheatWizard for removing very obvious NOOPs that I had for no reason XD.

Comment: @WheatWizard >_> Yeah, I was just testing you... Hahaha, thanks for pointing that out. I'll try to golf it more later, but I'll add that now lol

Answer (score 3):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), <s>31</s> 29 bytes

```
uo@[)o'U);!A?ro;o;o;os:'/u:''
```

`A` can also be substituted for `i`; <s>trying to figure out if there's a good way to squeeze another byte or two out of this.</s> -2 bytes thanks to MickyT! Also [outgolfed by MickyT](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/126778/67312)!

Fits on a 3x3x3 cube:

```
      u o @
      [ ) o
      ' U )
; ! A ? r o ; o ; o ; o
s : ' / u : ' ' . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . .
      . . .
      . . .
      . . .
```

[Watch it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ICAgICAgdSBvIEAKICAgICAgWyApIG8KICAgICAgJyBVICkKOyAhIEEgPyByIG8gOyBvIDsgbyA7IG8KcyA6ICcgLyB1IDogJyAnIC4gLiAuIC4KLiAuIC4gLiAuIC4gLiAuIC4gLiAuIC4KICAgICAgLiAuIC4KICAgICAgLiAuIC4KICAgICAgLiAuIC4K&input=YWJj&speed=10)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/7803yFaM189VNNa0dG@KN8aDIut1PVLrdTV//9PTEoGAA)

Comment: You can save a couple of bytes, by using a couple of increments for the last bracket.  This allows the bottom line to be compressed a bit `uo@[)o'U);!A?ro;o;o;os:'/u:''`

Answer (score 3):

## [Standard ML](http://www.mlton.org/), <s>52</s> 50 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Laikoni!

```ml
fn s=>String.translate(fn c=>"'"^str c^"':")s^"[]"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBCoMwEAXQq3xnkwjWA1TiunuXpYGgiQhjUjJDPX7q9vHk5MfJWnL7BUaCQ0sZ4uZF65H3UWvIwkGjvXl1MxnyohWrJ/OkXjy9P9QmfO@tsAn0isxlwFUqbx31U/sD)

`String.translate` is an unfortunately long name, but was 5 bytes shorter than using `concat`, `map`, and `explode`.

Comment: @Laikoni thanks! I always forget that operators have lower precedence than functions.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 47 bytes

```python
lambda a:`list(a)+[[]]`.replace(', ',':')[1:-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcNBCoQgFADQfaf4uFEZJ3CWwuznBi1M6DcZCX9UzIg5vfXg5X/dUny19T02wt@8IKCZKOxVoHxY69zUF58Jv15wBVxxw6XV5qldO7dAHrTpIJcQK6wixHxUIWVjrGN4/3iipGBIhRZ2AQ)

Comment: I had the same approach but I didn't figure out the `[1:-1]` part so it was longer than totallyhumans. +1

Comment: Strange that [the trivial solution](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8C2oCgzr4QrLb9IIVMhMw@ICkpLNDStCjRS81JsldSVtDO1ldStlDS5CjSUomOVNP//BwA) is just 3 bytes longer (in Python 3).

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```apl
'[]',⍨'.'⎕R'''&'':'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/hR2wT16Fh1nUe9K9T11B/1TQ1SV1dXU1e3UgdKKqircwGJRDDpkZqTk6@jEJ5flJOiDgA)

`'[]',⍨` the brackets appended to

`'.'` every character

`⎕R` PCRE **R**eplaced with

`'''&'':'` a quote, the match, a quote and a colon

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

A port of [Downgoat's JS solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/126421/58974).

```
ç"'$&':" +"[]
```

[Try it](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=5yInJCYnOiIgKyJbXQ==&input=ImFiYyI=)

Answer (score 2):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), <s>19</s> 18 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [Jordan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11261/jordan)

```
s/./'&':/g;s/$/[]/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N@f@/WF9PX11N3Uo/3bpYX0U/Olb///@M1JycfAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>75</s> 50  bytes

```r
function(x)cat(gsub("(.)","'\\1':",x),"[]",sep="")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfk5lUlFhUqZGbWpKRn1KsyZWmYKP7P600L7kkMz9Po0IzObFEI724NElDSUNPU0lHST0mxlDdSkmnQlNHKTpWSac4tcBWSUnzf5qGurqmNUi1ekyeOtAcCI0q4pGak5OvoxCeX5SToqiu@R8A)

Or for a non-regex approach:

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 63 bytes

```r
function(x)cat(sprintf("'%s':",el(strsplit(x,''))),'[]',sep='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYxNCsIwEIX3nqIWZGYgXsCfvTdwoV3UNsHAmISZEdrTx4grN@/xPvieVI4PGWXFl7dnnpU2oTvta3inyWJOuNA0GmqRmCxgDzuFQ@88o5po4Wi4OAAicnAbwKkv5zZrwJbHrwr3BO301//k4pmz665ZeN426QM)

It turns out that `sprintf` will recycle the format string to match the length of its input, which is a nice golf from the previous answer (which you can see in the edit history).

Comment: In the header for TIO, put library('methods').  That should allow `el` to work

Comment: @MickyT I could but I think at that point I'd need to include it as additional bytes, same as importing it from Python. I'm just complaining because It Works On My Machine (I don't know if any packages I have loaded in are causing that it to work though)

Comment: No problem, my default install here has it and it may be because TIO is using [RScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19680462/5158294) to execute the scripts

Comment: yeah, I did look into it but I screwed up the empty string case...just remembered you can compare strings to the empty string

Comment: I tried `paste0` again, still landed at the same number of bytes, unless I missed some obvious golfing somewhere.

Comment: No I missed the empty string trick when I looked at it.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) <strike>23</strike> 40 bytes

```
f=s=>!s?"[]":"'"+[...s].join("':'")+"':[]"
```

```js
f=s=>!s?"[]":"'"+[...s].join("':'")+"':[]"
console.log(f() + "\n") // `"[]"`
console.log(f("") + "\n") // `"[]"`
console.log(f("abc") + "\n") // "'a':'b':'c':[]"
```

Using spread element to convert string to array, `Array.prototype.join()` to concatenate `":"` characters

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. There seem to be some issues with your answer. 1.) This seems to be a snippet, not a function or full program. 2) This doesn't add quotes around the characters. 3.) You should use some additional formatting in the header of your answer (by putting a # in front of it).

Comment: @steenbergh See updated post

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is your StackOverflow account suspended? Sorry if this question is a bit inappropriate.

Comment: @guest271314. Ok

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 39 bytes

```php
<?while(~$c=$argn[$i++])echo"'$c':"?>[]
```

Run as pipe with `-F`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Convex](https://github.com/GamrCorps/Convex), 10 bytes

```
{`':`}%"[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87PK0ut@P@/OkHdKqFWVSk69v9/j9ScnHwdhfD8opwUAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 27 bytes

```
uosW?U.iv":'"^soso;os@o[]'/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/780vzjcPlQvs0zJSl0prji/ON86v9ghPzpWXf///5LU4hKukozMYgA)

```
      u o s
      W ? U
      . i v
" : ' " ^ s o s o ; o s
@ o [ ] ' / . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . .
      . . .
      . . .
      . . .
```

[Watch it run](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ICAgICAgdSBvIHMKICAgICAgVyA/IFUKICAgICAgLiBpIHYKIiA6ICcgIiBeIHMgbyBzIG8gOyBvIHMKQCBvIFsgXSAnIC8gLiAuIC4gLiAuIC4KLiAuIC4gLiAuIC4gLiAuIC4gLiAuIC4KICAgICAgLiAuIC4KICAgICAgLiAuIC4KICAgICAgLiAuIC4K&input=dGVzdAoxLi4yLi4z&speed=15)

A slightly different variation from Guiseppe's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/126620/31347).  This puts the colon and quote on the stack.  Then it loops through the input, swapping and outputting  the stack.  Only the input is scrapped and the colon and quote are retained.

Once the end of the input is reached the IP wonders around the cube a bit, adding and outputting the brackets.  There are a couple of redundant commands in the mix.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 43 bytes

```
->a{a==''?'[]':"'#{a.chars.join"':'"}':[]"}
```

Comment: You can remove the space after `join`.

Comment: Also, this doesn't return the correct output for an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 68 bytes

```
=IFERROR(CONCAT("'"&MID(A1,ROW(OFFSET(A1,,,LEN(A1))),1)&"':"),)&"[]"
```

Takes input from A1, outputs to whatever cell this formula is placed in. It's an array formula, so Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter to enter it.

11 of the bytes here are just for handling the empty string correctly, since Excel doesn't have a concept of arrays with zero elements.

The answer's pretty straightforward, but I did learn a couple things: IFERROR's second argument is taken to be `""` when left blank, and `&` will operate in an array-aware manner if and only if the construction is inside a function that will take an array (replacing `CONCAT(...)` with just `(...)` feels like it should work but it doesn't).

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 16 bytes

```
g39*Gyt19+v'[]'h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P93YUsu9ssTQUrtMPTpWPeP/f/XEpGR1AA)

A bit surprised not to see a MATL submission already.

#### Explanation:

```
	% implicit input, 'abc'
g	% convert to logical
	% STACK: {[1 1 1]}
39*	% multiply by 39, ASCII for ', elementwise.
	% STACK: {[39 39 39]}
G	% push input
	% STACK: {[39 39 39]; 'abc'}
yt	% copy from below and dup
	% STACK: {[39 39 39]; 'abc'; [39 39 39]; [39 39 39]}
19+	% add 19, elementwise, to get 58, ASCII for :
	% STACK: {[39 39 39]; 'abc'; [39 39 39]; [58 58 58]}
v	% vertically concatenate stack contents, implicitly converting to strings.
	% STACK: {'''
	%	  abc
	%	  '''
	%	  :::}
'[]'h	% push '[]' and horizontally concatenate, linearizing as needed
	% STACK: 'a':'b':'c':[]
	% implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `o`, 12 bytes

```
ƛ\'p‛':+₴;k[
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=o&code=%C6%9B%5C%27p%E2%80%9B%27%3A%2B%E2%82%B4%3Bk%5B&inputs=Hello%2C%20world!&header=&footer=)

```
ƛ        ;   # Map...
 \'p         # Prepend a '
    ‛':+     # Append a ':
        ₴    # Output without newline
          k[ # Push `[]`
             # Which is implicitly output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 26 bytes

```julia
!x=join("'".*x.*"':")*"[]"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/X7HCNis/M09DSV1JT6tCT0tJ3UpJU0spOlbpf0FRZl5JTp6GYrSSkp6eXqwmF5JIIqaQR2pOTr6OQnh@UU6KIkT6PwA)

input is a list of characters

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
,{ļ'pō':}ō[]
```

Explanation:

```
,{      }     iterate over the chars of string input
  ļ'          output "'"
    p         output the current char
     ō':      output "':"
         ō[]  output "[]"
```

In theory 10 byte `ļ'pō':}ō[]` could work, but, alas, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>43</s> 28 + 1 = <s>44</s> 29 bytes

*A whopping -15 bytes thanks to Value Ink.*

+1 byte for the `-p` flag.

```ruby
$_=gsub(/(.)/,"'\\1':")+"[]"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/XyXeNr24NElDX0NPU19HST0mxlDdSklTWyk6Vun/f4/UnJx8HYXw/KKclH/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA)

Comment: Since you're using the `-p` flag you can replace `$_.gsub!` with simply `gsub`, and you don't need the parantheses. That should save 8 bytes  in total: `gsub /(.)/,"'\\1':";gsub /$/,'[]'`

Comment: Edit: This is even shorter:Switch the `-p` flag with `-n` and the code with `$><<gsub(/(.)/,"'\\1':")+"[]"`

Answer (score 1):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), 26 bytes

```
:Lpp&p
'p|L
\'!d["
'M@,]"p
```

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell, 43 bytes

It's a `join(map(repr, input))` shape problem? That's simply 177 bytes of:

```
[linq.enumerable]::Aggregate([Linq.Enumerable]::Select(
[Object[]][Char[]]"$args", [Func[Object,String]]{"'$args'"})+(,'[]'),
[func[object,object,object]]{param($a,$b) $a+':'+$b})
```

Edit: can golf that down to a mere 171:

```
$e='[Linq.Enumerable]::';$o='Object';
"${e}Aggregate(${e}Select([$o[]][Char[]]""$args"",[Func[$o,$O]]{""'`$args'""})+(,'[]'),[func[$o,$o,$o]]{`$args[0]+':'+`$args[1]})"|iex
```

Oh all right, 43 bytes of:

```
(([char[]]"$args"|%{"'$_'"})+,'[]')-join':'
```

Comment: It does not work with the test case `"a" -> 'a':[]`. I'm sorry.

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser! 37 bytes `@($args|% t*y|%{"'$_'"})+'[]'-join':'`

Answer (score 1):

### Swift, <s>49</s> bytes

```
{$0.characters.reduce("",{$0+"'\($1)':"})+"[]"}
```

This is a lambda (closure in Swift). Because converting a `Character` Array to a string is `a.joined(seperator:"")` I've used `.reduce("",+)` as a golf. Kind of unreadable so broken down:

```
{
  $0.characters.reduce("", {
    $0 + "'\($1)':"
  }) + "[]"
}
```

because a map + converting to a string is too long, `reduce` will convert to a string for us as we go

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 27 bytes

```
i:0(?vd3*:o$oo':'o
o'[]'/;o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P9PKQMO@LMVYyypfJT9f3Uo9nytfPTpWXd86////4pKizLx0AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Noether](https://github.com/beta-decay/noether), 37 bytes

```
{I~sL0>}{sL("'"Psi/P"':"Pi1+~i)}"[]"P
```

[**Try it here!**](https://beta-decay.github.io/noether?code=e0l-c0wwPn17c0woIiciUHNpL1AiJzoiUGkxK35pKX0iW10iUA&input=ImNhdHMi)

Takes input between quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 51 bytes

Anonymous VBE immedate function that takes input as string from cell `[A1]`, 
 iterates across the input string, splitting it by character and then outputs to the VBE immediate window

```vb
For i=1To[Len(A1)]:?"'"Mid([A1],i,1)"':";:Next:?"[]
```

#### Previous, Longer Versions

```vb
1:  a=Split(StrConv([A1],64),Chr(0)):For i=0To[Len(A1)-1]:?"'"a(i)"':";:Next:?"[]"

2:  ?"'"Mid(Join(Split(StrConv([A1],64),Chr(0)),"':'"),1,4*Len([A1])-1)"[]"

3:  ?"'"Left(Join(Split(StrConv([A1],64),Chr(0)),"':'"),4*Len([A1])-1)"[]"

4:  ?"'"Replace(Left(Strconv([A1],64),2*Len([A1])-1),Chr(0),"':'")":[]"    

5:  ?Replace(Left("'"&StrConv([A1],64),2*Len([A1])),Chr(0),"':'")"':[]"

6:  ?"'"Left(Replace(StrConv([A1],64),Chr(0),"':'"),4*Len([A1])-1)"[]"

7:  ?"'"Replace(Replace(StrConv([A1],64),Chr(0),"':'")&" ","' ","[]")

8:  For i=1To Len([A1]):?"'"&Mid([A1],i,1);"':";:Next:?"[]"

9:  For i=1To[Len(A1)]:?"'"&Mid([A1],i,1);"':";:Next:?"[]"

10: For i=1To[Len(A1)]:?"'"Mid([A1],i,1)"':";:Next:?"[]"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 34 bytes

```
"'"<>#<>"':"&/@Characters@#<>"[]"&
```

Anonymous function. Takes a string as input and returns a string as output. Just separates the input's characters, inserts `'...':` around each, and adds `[]` to the end.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 11 bytes

```
ＦＳ⁺⁺'ι':¦[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9nmXv92x@1LgLiNTP7VS3OrQsOvb//8TilLT/uokA) Explanation provided as AST.

Answer (score 1):

### Rust, 69 bytes

```
|s:&str|s.chars().map(|s|format!("'{}':",s)).collect::<String>()+"[]"
```

Couldn't find anything shorter than the trivial solution.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 60 bytes

```java
String f(String s){return s.replaceAll(".","['$0']:")+"[]";}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 48 bytes

```
-[-[<++>->++>-<<]>]<<,[<-.>.<.+<.>>,]<<<<+++.++.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fN1o32kZb207XDkTY2MTaxdrY6ETb6OrZ6dnoadvo2dnpAEVsgGq09YDo//9EAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╩8┼Φv╚▀╛┴►
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=ca38c5e876c8dfbec110&i=abc&a=1)

Comment: Never thought of doing it this way ...

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 34 bytes

```
{it.fold(""){a,v->a+"'$v':"}+"[]"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY2xCsIwFEX3fsXzITShrR8QsF0d3BwcxOFB0hKMiaRplpJvj9H2Thfu4dyXC0bbHMmAVPMykRfAbsFrO3HoetgqnPOqw2l0RjJEvlIbu54arI@xFpgafDwx5XGx8CZtGYe1gpKfdd4F4BXJq7aqrIMAxD/xKWNg@zPbWM6rlC/KGNfC3XkjD18)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ahead](https://github.com/ajc2/ahead), 25 bytes

```
v>"]["W@
>jri''r
^W"':"W<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xITUz5/7/MTik2WincgcsuqyhTXb2IKy5cSd1KKdzm///EpOQUAA)

Answer (score 1):

### Burlesque - 21 bytes

```
m{bx"'~':"jf~}"[]"_+Q
```

Longer versions:

```
XX{bx"'~':"jf~}\m"[]"_+Q
```

Burlesque shows characters with a single `'` i.e. `'x` instead of `'x'` which is why we have to surround characters manually with two `'`s.

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 47 bytes

```forth
: f bounds ?do ." '"i 1 type ." ':"loop ." []";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY0xDsIwDEX3nuLLCwtBKt1aCVZu0AExpE0ClQK2knTg9CGhMH2/72fZcUgPdXc1cu7hMPH6MhFnwzgQdrSgRXqL/VJPnlnqeL3RUHzB0axSNNjnkjbxD3XRdlDQU0QUPdtYL6FOoPJoDhiaJlIBqaF/ebHe8x4jB29KlT8)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f          \ start a new word definition
  bounds     \ get the starting and ending addresses of the string
  ?do        \ loop from start to end (skip if start=end)       
    ." '"    \ output '
    i 1 type \ print the character at the current address
    ." ':"   \ output ':
  loop       \ end loop
  ." []"     \ output []
;            \ end word definition
```

Answer (score 1):

## Rust macro, 185 bytes

```rust
macro_rules!f{([])=>{['[',']']};([$c:expr]$($o:tt)*)=>{[$($o,)*'\'',$c,'\'',':','[',']']};([$c:expr$(,$r:tt)*]$($o:tt)*)=>{f!([$($r),*]$($o)*'\''$c'\''':')};($($r:tt)*)=>{f!([$($r)*])}}
```

Defines a macro that takes a comma-seperated sequence of character tokens and expands to an array of characters.

[try it online](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=macro_rules!%20f%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20the%20macro%20is%20a%20tt%20muncher%20where%20the%20inputs%20are%20in%20brackets%20with%20the%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20accumulator%20after%20that.%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20the%20base%20case%20for%20an%20empty%20array%0A%20%20%20%20(%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20expand%20to%20the%20brackets%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B%27%5B%27%2C%20%27%5D%27%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20the%20base%20case%20for%20a%20single%20element%0A%20%20%20%20(%5B%24c%3Aexpr%5D%20%24(%24o%3Att)*)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B%24(%24o%2C)*%20%27%5C%27%27%2C%20%24c%2C%20%27%5C%27%27%2C%20%27%3A%27%2C%20%27%5B%27%2C%20%27%5D%27%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20the%20recursive%20case%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20extract%20a%20characters%20from%20the%20input%20token%20stream%0A%20%20%20%20(%5B%24c%3Aexpr%20%24(%2C%24r%3Att)*%5D%20%24(%24o%3Att)*)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f!(%5B%24(%24r)%2C*%5D%20%24(%24o)*%20%27%5C%27%27%20%24c%20%27%5C%27%27%20%27%3A%27)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20entry%20point%0A%20%20%20%20(%24(%24r%3Att)*)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20call%20the%20recursive%20part%20by%20wrapping%20the%20arguments%20in%20brackets%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f!(%5B%24(%24r)*%5D)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20assert_eq!(%5B%27%5B%27%2C%20%27%5D%27%5D%2C%20f!())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20assert_eq!(%5B%27%5C%27%27%2C%20%27a%27%2C%20%27%5C%27%27%2C%20%27%3A%27%2C%20%27%5B%27%2C%20%27%5D%27%5D%2C%20f!(%27a%27))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20assert_eq!(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27%5C%27%27%2C%20%27H%27%2C%20%27%5C%27%27%2C%20%27%3A%27%2C%20%27%5C%27%27%2C%20%27e%27%2C%20%27%5C%27%27%2C%20%27%3A%27%2C%20%27%5C%27%27%2C%20%27l%27%2C%20%27%5C%27%27%2C%20%27%3A%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27%5C%27%27%2C%20%27l%27%2C%20%27%5C%27%27%2C%20%27%3A%27%2C%20%27%5C%27%27%2C%20%27o%27%2C%20%27%5C%27%27%2C%20%27%3A%27%2C%20%27%5C%27%27%2C%20%27%2C%27%2C%20%27%5C%27%27%2C%20%27%3A%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27%5C%27%27%2C%20%27%20%27%2C%20%27%5C%27%27%2C%20%27%3A%27%2C%20%27%5C%27%27%2C%20%27W%27%2C%20%27%5C%27%27%2C%20%27%3A%27%2C%20%27%5C%27%27%2C%20%27o%27%2C%20%27%5C%27%27%2C%20%27%3A%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27%5C%27%27%2C%20%27r%27%2C%20%27%5C%27%27%2C%20%27%3A%27%2C%20%27%5C%27%27%2C%20%27l%27%2C%20%27%5C%27%27%2C%20%27%3A%27%2C%20%27%5C%27%27%2C%20%27d%27%2C%20%27%5C%27%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27%3A%27%2C%20%27%5B%27%2C%20%27%5D%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%5B..%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f!(%27H%27%2C%20%27e%27%2C%20%27l%27%2C%20%27l%27%2C%20%27o%27%2C%20%27%2C%27%2C%20%27%20%27%2C%20%27W%27%2C%20%27o%27%2C%20%27r%27%2C%20%27l%27%2C%20%27d%27)%5B..%5D%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%7D)

### Explanation

```rust
macro_rules! f {
    // the macro is a tt muncher where the inputs are in brackets with the
    // accumulator after that.

    // the base case for an empty array
    ([]) => {
        // expand to the brackets
        ['[', ']']
    };
    // the base case for a single element
    ([$c:expr] $($o:tt)*) => {
        [$($o,)* '\'', $c, '\'', ':', '[', ']']
    };
    // the recursive case
    // extract a characters from the input token stream
    ([$c:expr $(,$r:tt)*] $($o:tt)*) => {
        f!([$($r),*] $($o)* '\'' $c '\'' ':')
    };

    // entry point
    ($($r:tt)*) => {
        // call the recursive part by wrapping the arguments in brackets
        f!([$($r)*])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), 82 bytes

```
2a2x1v2m9m3a2x2v9a9a1a2x3v1x1f1r3x1v2e2x4v2v1o4v1o2v1o3v1o1f0x1x2f9m5m1a1o2a1o0x1f
```

Works for any input string terminated with the control character STX (U+0002).

**Explanation** (with `0x` commands removed)

```
2a2x1v                             # Set variable 1 equal to 2
2m9m3a2x2v                         # Set variable 2 equal to 39 ("'")
9a9a1a2x3v                         # Set variable 3 equal to 58 (":")
1x1f                               # Function 1
    1r                             # Read a byte of input
      3x1v2e                       # Jump to function 2 if it equals variable 1
            2x4v                   # Otherwise, store the byte in variable 4
                2v1o4v1o2v1o3v1o   # Output it, using variables 2 and 3 to format it as required
                                1f # Jump back to the start of function 1
1x2f                               # Function 2
    9m5m1a1o2a1o                   # Output "[]"
1f                                 # Call function 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 16 bytes

```
÷⑷\&⑨ⁿ:"\:⅍⅀⑸`[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATAAz/9rZWf//8O34pG3XCbikajigb86Ilw64oWN4oWA4pG4YFtd//9IZWxsbywgV29ybGQ)

This is what you call "the result of me not implementing things properly".

Answer (score 1):

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 52 bytes

Pretty simple solution.

```erlang
f(X)->lists:join(":",[["'"|[I|"'"]]||I<-X]++["[]"]).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcoxDsMgDEDRPaegXgpK6AFQlbk5QSNZHqIWKlduqAApC3cn/OUvzyfZ9o/1@ZX4X9rQgl6NnYVzye4bedfgYEKEK1Rcah9RrcvdrjSOCEhA5tZ@W4dIRtl5UD2OLhyJi9dBw8OLxEk9Y5L3BUznJw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), <s>94</s> 69 bytes

```
listen to S
cut S
O's ""
while S
let O be+"'"+roll S+"':"

say O+"[]"
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 36 bytes

```lua
print((...):gsub(".","'%1':").."[]")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0RDQ09PT9Mqvbg0SUNJT0lHSV3VUN1KSVNPTyk6Vknz////Hqk5Ofk6CuH5RTkpigA)

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 5.9, 45 bytes

```swift
let f={($0+"").map{"'\($0)':"}.joined()+"[]"}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
”';Ð€;€⁾':⁾[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw1x168MTHjWtsQbiR4371K2ARHTs////lTyASvJ1FMrzi3JSFJUA)

Explanation:

```
”';Ð€;€⁾':⁾[]

”';Ð€            Concatenate ' to the beginning of each element
     ;€⁾':       Concatenate ': to the end of each element
          ⁾[]    Implicit concatenation of literal "[]"
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to add single quotes around each character.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Noticed as soon as I posted it. Fixing now.

Answer (score 0):

### CJam, <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
q{`':`}%"[]"
```

Explanation:

```
q    e# Input: "test"
{    e# For each character: ['t 'e 's 't]
  `  e#   Get the string representation: ["'t" "'e" "'s" "'t"]
  ': e#   Push the character ':': ["'t" ': "'e" ': "'s" ': "'t" ':]
  `  e#   Get the string representation: ["'t" "':" "'e" "':" "'s" "':" "'t" ':]
}%   e# End
"[]" e# Push the string "[]"
e# Implicit print: 't':'e':'s':'t':[]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [braingasm](https://github.com/daniero/braingasm/), 18 bytes

```
,[39.."':".,]"[]".
```

Just a simple loop, reading one byte at a time and printing the necessary stuff before and after the input, then the final square brackets.

Test run:

```
$ echo -n Hello | braingasm haskell_strings.bg 
'H':'e':'l':'l':'o':[]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 35 bytes

```
[_l;||X=X+@'`+_sA,a,1|+B+@:`]?X+@[]
```

### Explanation

```
[    |         FOR a = 1 TO
 _l |           the length of
   ;              input string
X=X+@'`        Add to Z$ a literal '
   +_sA,a,1|   and a 1-char substring at index a of the input A$
   +B          and another quote (defining it as literal created B$)
   +@:`        and a literal :
]              NEXT
?X+@[]         PRINT Z$ and a literal [] (no closing backtick because EOF)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Octave, 37 bytes

```matlab
@(s)(s&&printf("'%c':",s))+puts("[]")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQaNYU6NYTa2gKDOvJE1DSV01Wd1KSadYU1O7oLSkWEMpOlZJ8z9XYh6Q6ZGak5OvoxCeX5SToqRpzfUfAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 29 bytes

```
VRl1-M[R>#'<"':">>>>v]R"[]"&@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/8/LCjHUNc3OshOWd1GSd1KyQ4IymKDlKJjldQc/v//75Gak5OvoxCeX5STovg1L183OTE5IxUA)

Currently a bug in Braingolf foreach loops that breaks them when handling 2 adjacent duplicates (such as the `l`s in `Hello`), so I have to use this method that costs me an extra 13 bytes

If foreach loops worked properly, it would've been this, which is only 16 bytes:

```
{>#'<"':"}"[]"&@
```

### Explanation

```
VRl1-M[R>#'<"':">>>>v]R"[]"&@  Implicit input from commandline args
VRl1-M                         Create stack2, push length of stack1 - 1 to stack2
      [..............]         Do-While loop, will run for each item on stack1
       R>                      Return to stack2, move ToS to bottom
         #'<                   Push single quote and move BoS back to top
            "':"               Push single quote and colon
                >>>>           Rotate stack to next item from input
                    v          Switch to stack2 for loop counting
                      R"[]"&@  Switch to stack1, push [] and print entire stack
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), 37 bytes

```
{it.replaceAll(~/./,{"'$it':"})+"[]"}
```

(It's an anonymous closure, which can be called thus `{...}("hello")` or via a name thus `f = {...};f("hello")`.)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 36 bytes

```
lambda s:':'.join(map(repr,[*s,[]]))
```

A variation of [Rod's one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/126429/7258).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRodhK3UpdLys/M08jN7FAoyi1oEgnWqtYJzo2VlOTq6AoM69EI01DSUlTRwFIJUJpj9ScnHwdhfD8opwUJU3N//@5AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [setlx](https://randoom.org/Software/SetlX), 36 bytes

```
s|->join(["'"+x+"':":x in s],"")+"[]";
```

#### Explanation:

```
s |->                               // a function taking an argument s
    join(                           // join:
        [ "'" + x + "':" : x in s], // a list from each char wrapped in quotes
        ""                          // with the empty string
    ) 
    + []                            // add an empty list to the string, this will convert it to the string "[]"
;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 42 bytes

```
#(str(apply str(for[c %](str"'"c"':")))[])
```

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript 33 bytes

```
f=s=>s.replace(/(.)/g,"'$1':")+'[]'
```

Answer (score 0):

### ><>, 25 bytes

```
i:0(?v":''"o{ooo
o"[]"<;o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P9PKQMO@TMlKXV0pvzo/P58rXyk6VsnGOv//f4/UnJx8HYXw/KKcFAA)

Comment: You can save a couple of bytes by taking input through the `-s` flag

Answer (score 0):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 9 bytes

```
♂è[]@q':j
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8///RzKbDK6JjHQrVrbL@/1dKTEpWAgA)

Explanation:

```
♂è[]@q':j
           implicit input ("abc")
♂è         push a list containing the string representation of each character (['a', 'b', 'c'])
  []@q     add an empty list to the end of that list (['a', 'b', 'c', [])
      ':j  join with colons ("'a':'b':'c':[]")
           implicit print ('a':'b':'c':[])
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 52 bytes

```
s->c=concat;c(c([Str("'",x,"':")|x<-Vec(s)],["[]"]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYyxCsMgFEV/5XGXKDx/oG0ydy80g3WQ16QEJIo6pNB/t2a5Bw6Hm3zezCe1lcZWzCSjxF18vYoSZR81KwzggzFcoH/HzTwXUUU7trAOTuvmUwpfVchMlPK2V4UXQIU6Tgdae6@ZLMAEf859CSEyzTGHd/9ofw)

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 81 bytes

```
	N =INPUT
S	N LEN(1) . X REM . N	:F(O)
	O =O "'" X "':"	:(S)
O	OUTPUT =O "[]"
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9NPwdbTLyA0hCsYyPRx9dMw1FTQU4hQCHL1BdJ@nFZuGv6aXJz@Crb@CkrqSkAZJXUrJU4rjWBNLn9O/9AQoF6wXHSsEpern8v//x6pOTn5Ogrh@UU5KQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 30 bytes

```
D,f,@*,39@39 58
L^~,€{f}"[]"BF
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ03HQUvH2NLB2FLB1ILLJ65O51HTmuq0WqXoWCUnt/8qOYm5SSmJCoZ29lz@XFz4uP//Kyn9V0oE4aTkFCUA)

### How it works

```
D,f,@*,		; Create a function, 'f', that
		; that takes one argument, and returns the full stack
		; Example argument:	['a']
	39@	; Prepend 39;	STACK = [39 'a']
	39 58	; Push 39, 58;	STACK = [39 'a' 39 58]
		; Return the full stack
		; 39 is the ordinal of ' and 58 of :

L^~,		; Create a lambda function
		; The ^ converts all integers to characters, then concatenates, when returning
		; The ~ unpacks the argument beforehand
		; Example argument:		['a' 'b' 'c']
	€{f}	; Run 'f' over each;	STACK = [[39 'a' 39 58] [39 'b' 39 58] [39 'c' 39 58]]
	"[]"	; Push '[]';		STACK = [[39 'a' 39 58] [39 'b' 39 58] [39 'c' 39 58] '[]']
	BF	; Flatten;		STACK = [39 'a' 39 58 39 'b' 39 58 39 'c' 39 58 '[]']
		; The ^ flag converts integers to characters:
		;			STACK = ["'" 'a' "'" ':' "'" 'b' "'" ':' "'" 'c' "'" ':' '[]']
		; Then concatenates them into a single string:
		;			STACK = ["'a':'b':'c':[]"]
		; And returns the top value:
		;			Return "'a':'b':'c':[]"
```

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC 3, <strike>53</strike> 48 bytes

-5 with the `WHILE` trick, thanks 12Me21!

```
LINPUT S$WHILE""<S$?"'"+SHIFT(S$)+"':";
WEND?"[]
```

Explainer:

```
LINPUT S$              'Read line from console
WHILE ""<S$            'WHILE S$ is not empty
 ?"'"+SHIFT(S$)+"':";  'Print 'x': where x is popped off the front of S$
WEND                   'End WHILE
?"[]"                  'Print []
```

Comment: snail remembe*r*

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
J':`:søms
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/30vdKsGq@PCO3OL///8reaTm5OTrKITnF@WkKAEA)

#### Explanation

```
J':`:søms  Implicit input                                 "abc"
       ms  String representation of each character        ["'a'","'b'","'c'"]
   `:sø    Append the string of an empty list to the end  ["'a'","'b'","'c'","[]"]
J':        Join with a colon character                    "'a':'b':'c':[]"
```

Answer (score 0):

## F#, 55 bytes

My first F#, which means it probably isn't very good. <sub>My SmileBASIC answer is beating it, even...</sub>

```
fun s->List.reduce(+)[for c in s->sprintf"'%c':"c]+"[]"
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##JYyxCsMwEEP3fIV6EJIQ0uwd8gXdO4QM6eXcGood7PNQ6L@7bqpBSEg8Ewf2QXIeR9yCVcHbpwDr9qTFoU9B1GDdA6seTdwGb474sk5OVWuSQxymq416DrIllrbvZuMD@IcoU9wLQQ01NTcXAi89zQt1oPXOVKHoM@H/AdWRcv4C) Golfing tips are appreciated

Comment: The space before the last `c` can be dropped.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 15 bytes

```
aJ':JW''AL":[]"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/0UvdyitcXd3RR8kqOlbp////Hqk5OfkA)

### Explanation

```
aJ':JW''AL":[]" a → input                     Example → "Hi"
aJ':            join characters with ':'              → 'H:i"
    JW''        join and wrap that with single quotes → "'H':'i'"
        AL":[]" Append list ":[]"                     → "'H':'i':[]"
                Concatenation has high precedence, so AL is used.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `P`, 75 [bits<sup>v1</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 9.375 bytes

```
\'vø.¾SJ\:j
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJQPSIsIiIsIlxcJ3bDuC7CvlNKXFw6aiIsIiIsIkknbSBub3QgZ29pbmcgdG8gc3VnYXJjb2F0IGl0IC0geW91IGNhbiBwcmVzcyBjIHRvIHBhcnJ5IGF0dGFja3MiXQ==)

I'm not going to sugarcoat it - you can press `c` to golf your answers

### Explained

```
\'vø.¾SJ\:j
\'vø.       # Surround each character with "'"
     ¾SJ    # append the string "[]" to that (the global array is initially empty, and the P flag stringify lists as square brackets instead of angle brackets)
        \:j # join on ":" and output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ʋ':'j''ṛʋ:[]+
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWG091q1upZ6mrP9w5-1S3VXSs9pLipORiqOyCdUoeqTk5-ToK4flFOSlKEFEA)

##### Explanation

```python
ʋ':'j''ṛʋ:[]+  # Implicit input
ʋ':'j          # Join the input by the string "':'"
     ''ṛ       # Surround this string by "'"
        ʋ:[]+  # Append the string ":[]"
               # Implicit output
```