# Let's make Diet Haskell

Tags: code-golf, string, haskell

Haskell has tuples that can be written as

```
(a,b,c)
```

However this is just syntactic sugar for

```
(,,)a b c
```

In general an **n** tuple can be formed with **n-1** `,`s between `(`...`)` followed by its elements separated by spaces.  For example the 7-tuple, `(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)` can be formed by

```
(,,,,,,)1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Since Haskell does not have 1-tuples they cannot be formed.  You will also not be held responsible for empty tuples.

Nested tuples can be formed using parens to override the order of operations.

```
((1,2),3) == (,)((,)1 2)3
```

As part of [our pursuit to remove all syntactic sugar from Haskell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/126410/sugar-free-syntax)  I am going to ask you to write a program that removes syntactic sugar from Haskell's tuples as well.

Your program should take a tuple, an array, or a string representing a sugary tuple and should output a string representing a "sugar-free" tuple.  Input tuples will only ever contain positive integers or other tuples.

Since we are golfing here your output should be short.  It should not contain unnecessary

- Spaces.  Spaces should be used only to separate arguments of a tuple functions and should not appear after a `)` or before a `(`
- Parentheses.  Parentheses should be used only when forming tuple functions or when nesting tuples.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) question so answers will be scored in bytes with fewer bytes being better.

### Test cases

```
(1,2)     -> (,)1 2
(1,2,3)   -> (,,)1 2 3
((1,2),3) -> (,)((,)1 2)3
(1,2,3,4) -> (,,,)1 2 3 4
(1,(2,3)) -> (,)1((,)2 3)
(10,1)    -> (,)10 1
```

Comment: If I'm not missing anything, you cover 1-tuples but not empty tuples..? Are empty tuples valid input?

Comment: @totallyhuman You do not have to handle empty tuples.

Comment: The 5th test-case has an extra `,`

Comment: @H.PWiz You mean that `2,3` should be `2 3` instead?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Yes

Comment: Also by "numbers" do you mean "positive integers"?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Sure, that is fine

Comment: If our language doesn't have tuples, would an array suffice?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Sure I've already allowed that for answers.  I can't edit the question right now feel free to add it.

Comment: Suggested test cases: `((1,(2,3)),4,(5,6))` and `(1,(2,3),4)`.

Answer (score 17):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>169</s> 148 bytes

```hs
init.tail.fst.([]%)
p:k="(,"
l%('(':r)|(y,x:s)<-[]%r,m<-y:l=last$m%(p:s):[(p:p:(l>>k)++x:foldl(\r x->x++[' '|x>k,r>k]++r)[x]m,s)|x<',']
l%r=lex r!!0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5NboMwEIX3PsUEBTEWNoKQlQWcoF11SVhYaWgRhlqGSo5Kr17KX1BmM09vvpk3n7Krb0qNZXoZq7bqg15WKii7PsC8cCnRok4dZA5RLnroCUMHvDMrOprwCTCsSfhdqFTJrj82LuppIvKpaYEqy2rq@1aUX@pd4cWA5Zn1/dwDb7BZzUxWF75vaG6LhnV0sInHvGKKMqm6WTCHQzg2smohhUbqV0D93b/15qWFAEoKR8gdjNiJOmzpLF7UYm16cdl50zgjqw5Z9AzPSEHIDyeLAXPxDJDRCE5kO/7wFhNisidtKK44jcmeuy1sG3Am@xeP8/PSNKJk/ekpOISI8N/x71oq@dGN/Kr1Pw) Takes the tuple as a string. `init.tail.fst.([]%)` is the anonymous main function. Bind it to e.g. `f` and use like `f "(3,(14,1),4,7)"`, which yields `"(,,,)3((,)14 1)4 7"`.

Why is the input not provided as a Haskell tuple, you ask? Because Haskell is strongly typed, a tuple `(1,2)` has type `(Int,Int)`<sup>1</sup> and a tuple `(1,(2,3))` has type `(Int,(Int,Int))`. Thus a function which accepts the first kind of tuple can not be applied to the second kind, and especially there can be no function which takes an arbitrary tuple<sup>2</sup>.

#### Explanation:

- `p:k="(,"` is a short way to assign `p` to `'('` and `k` to `","`.
- `(%)` is the recursive parsing and converting function. The first argument is a list of already parsed tuple entries, the second argument is the remainder of the original string. Each call returns a tuple of the current converted tuple (as a string and enclosed in brackets) and the remainder of the string.

  - `l%('(':r)` If the string starts with an opening bracket, we need to parse a new tuple entry.
    `(y,x:s)<-[]%r` We recursively apply `%` and get a tuple entry `y` and the remaining string splitted into the next character `x` and the rest of the string `s`.
    `m<-y:l` We add the new entry `y` to the current list of already found entries `l` and call the result `m`.
  - The next character `x` is now either a comma `,` or a closing bracket `)`. The `last$ <B> :[ <A> |x<',']` is just a shorter way of writing `if x == ')' then <A> else <B>`.
  - So if a `,` is next, we need to recursively parse the next entry: `m%(p:s)` We prepend an opening bracket in order to end up in the right case and pass the list of already found entries `m`.
  - If otherwise `x == ')'`, we finished the current tuple and need to do the required transformation: `(p:p:(l>>k)++x:foldl(\r x->x++[' '|x>k,r>k]++r)[x]m,s)`

    - `p:p:(l>>k)++x:` If we have found *n* entries, then `m` has *n* elements and `y`, the list before adding the most recently found element, has *n-1* entries. This comes in handy as we need *n-1* `,` for an `n` element tuple and `l>>k` works on lists as *"concatenate the list `k` with itself as many times as `y` has elements"*. Thus this first part yields some string like `"((,,,)"`.
    - `foldl(\r x->x++[' '|x>k,r>k]++r)[x]m` concatenates the elements of `m` (in reverse order, because by adding new entries to the front `m` itself was constructed in reverse order) while adding only spaces in between two elements if they are both numbers: `[' '|x>k,r>k]` we check if the current entries `x` and `r` are numbers by lexicographically comparing them to `","` - if they are not numbers, they are already a tuple representation enclosed in brackets, and `'(' < ','` holds.
  - If the pattern match `l%('(':r)` right at the beginning fails, then we end up on the last line: `l%r=lex r!!0`. This means we need to parse a number and return the number and the remainder of the string. Luckily there is the `lex` function which does exactly that (It parses the next valid Haskell token, not just numbers). However the resulting tuple is wrapped into a list, so we use `!!0` to get the first element of the list.
- `init.tail.fst.([]%)` is the main function which takes a string and applies `%` with an empty list to it. E.g. for an input `"(1,2)"`, , applying `([]%)` yields `("((,)1 2)","")`, so the outer tuple and brackets need to be removed. `fst` gets the first element of the tuple, `tail` removes the closing bracket and `init` the opening one.

**Edit:** Many thanks to [@Ørjan Johansen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66041/%c3%98rjan-johansen) for golfing a total of **21 bytes**!

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Actually, the type is *(Num t1, Num t) => (t, t1)*, but that's a diferent story.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> Ignoring polymorphic functions like *id*, which cannot actually work with their input.</sup>

Comment: One could write a polymorphic function using a typeclass `Desugarable`, but one would have to declare instances for `Int`, and *all* tuple types.

Comment: `g` can be shortened to `foldr1(\x r->x++[' '|x>k,r>k]++r)` and inlined.

Comment: @Bergi: …and one [_cannot_ declare instances for truly _all_ tuple types](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Show.html#line-264). :-) (Try: `show (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5)` in GHCi, then add a `,6` at the end and try again.)

Comment: @wchargin [62 of them would suffice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2979762/1048572). `GHC.Show` just is not silly enough to do it :-)

Comment: Improving the inlining for six more bytes: Use `m<-y:l`, fold left instead of right, and use `[x]` as initial value. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU5Na4NAEL3vr5hIgrM4Fo05Lbq/oD31aCUIjVRcraxb2FD7262uRjKXebx5H/NVDs1NqWnqRZN5SB5TJ/TRF5qPeCcrBp6GeXHS1KbhXahMlYM5tifs54vI59ULVFI2PAisqL7Vp8IPDTaUNghyH/zRyoa0bIog0Dy3RUsDH23qk1/MVTpTNwv6cIhYBcOIV2HoujYOWd3VBszUlnUHGbRl/wbY/5h3o187eIGKwxFyD2M6c4/cpsQhR23YsXTZMC6SFUcUP4sXScHYb8gcAcuEEpB4DGe2hT84R0LC9qZNiqucJ2zv3QybAy5s/@IRv5jmE2frT0/FEcQs/Jv@AQ "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: `f` can be anonymous: `init.tail.fst.([]%)`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Bergi "A 63-tuple is too large for GHC (max size is 62) Workaround: use nested tuples or define a data type" Wow, TIL!

Comment: In [some](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141628/3527) [answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141596/3527), the input is a data structure that is or mimics a tuple. Could you not take a tuple of tuples as input? I think that would simplify and shorten the code.

Comment: @GolfWolf I'm not sure what you mean by "taking tuples of tuples" what is not already covered in the explanation why I can't use tuples. One can not use nested lists, because Haskell's  lists require all elements to be of the same type, so you can not have a list `[1,[2,3]]`, because `Int` and `[Int]` are different types. One could however define a custom data type like `data T=I Int|U[T]`, or use Template Haskell as [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141655/56433) shows.

Comment: @Laikoni Duh! Sorry! I was *so* wrong. Not only I did not pay attention to your answer, but with a little more thought it would have been obvious...

Comment: @Bergi actually you could use dependently typed heterogeneous lists to represent the tuple. Just encode it with 2-tuples (cons) and unit (Nil). Though, I doubt it will safe you bytes.

Answer (score 9):

### Haskell, <del>141 bytes</del> 138 bytes<sup><sub><sub>(Thanks to Ørjan Johansen)</sub></sub></sup>

```
import Language.Haskell.TH
f(TupE l)='(':tail(","<*l)++')':""%l
q%(LitE(IntegerL i):l)=q++show i++" "%l
_%(e:l)='(':f e++')':""%l
_%[]=[]
```

`f` has type `Exp -> String`.

- Input: a [Template Haskell `Exp`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.12.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH.html#t:Exp)ression (i.e., the standard AST representation of arbitrary-type Haskell values – basically, parsed Haskell code before type checking); must represent a tuple containing only nonnegative integer numbers and other such tuples.
- Output: a string containing the desugared syntax for that tuple expression.

Demo:

```
$ ghci TupDesugar.hs 
GHCi, version 8.3.20170711: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/sagemuej/.ghc/ghci.conf
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/sagemuej/.ghci
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( TupDesugar.hs, interpreted )
Ok, 1 module loaded.
*Main> :set -XTemplateHaskell -XQuasiQuotes
*Main> f <$> runQ [|(1,2)|]
"(,)1 2"
*Main> f <$> runQ [|(1,2,3)|]
"(,,)1 2 3"
*Main> f <$> runQ [|((1,2),3)|]
"(,)((,)1 2)3"
*Main> f <$> runQ [|(1,2,3,4)|]
"(,,,)1 2 3 4"
*Main> f <$> runQ [|(1,(2,3))|]
"(,)1((,)2 3)"
*Main> f <$> runQ [|(10,1)|]
"(,)10 1"
```

Comment: You can change `")"++` to `')':` in two places, and save the space after the `tail` by moving it outside parentheses.

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 119 bytes

```hs
data T=I Int|U[T]
f(U t)="(("++init(t>>",")++')':foldr(\x y->f x++[' '|f x>",",y>","]++y)")"t
f(I n)=show n
init.tail.f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU5Na4NAEL3vr3hIwR12FVc9FfQutKfGk/UgpCZSY0KypZGmv93uaqoWujDDzvua2VeX97e2HYZtpStskgxZp295sSlZzXNoShzOHSGartFcp6kjHRLCJfexPrbbM3@9ovfSGlchChfuzfysRva2l0L05JCjTVaGjpLL/viJju0SG@frqmn9ejhUTYcEh@r0DH760C/6/NTBx47wgIIhLzIomSEs5WowFU3Aip@xlchUvIC2T94ZC8yo/osanQwlY18e40qGhOl5KbgkhXBEZUQLOsKIGB/1EzXJ@WSh6G6S8cz9uhBbjtvExaes0ZBkuEAq@nNCADWvsoH3G@ZdJtH7Hn4A) This uses a custom data type `T` to represent tuples, that is a tuple `((1,2),3)` is represented as `U[U[I 1,I 2],I 3]`. Example usage: `init.tail.f $ U[U[I 1,I 2],I 3]` yields `(,)((,)1 2)3`.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 110 bytes

```python
def f(t):
 s='('+','*~-len(t)+')';c=0
 for i in t:
	try:s+=' '*c+`+i`;c=1
	except:s+='(%s)'%f(i);c=0
 return s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1BCsMgEEXX8RSzCTMTLTTpzuJdAqlSoRjRCTSbXt1Ku/3vPX4@5bmnpbWHDxBI2CqoDgk1Gpw@l5dPfdTIeN/cVUHYC0SICcSqQcppq3YIOG161XHtzqwG/958lh@hsTKOgSL/8@LlKAlqyyUm6Ycx5UOIudFsgBYDN@Yv)

Takes a `tuple`.

Answer (score 4):

## GNU sed, <s>149</s> 82 + 2 = 84 bytes

+2 bytes for `-r` flag.

```
y/(),/<>'/
:
s/([^<>']+)'/,\1 /
t
s/ ?<(,+)([^>]+)>/((\1)\2)/
t
s/^.|(\)) |.$/\1/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYmxDsIwDET3fEUGpNqqW@PChKr0QzCdQIiFItIFqd@OccJy9@5evl3NPgxIPKaGwylkhvPsfGmxYVKJHFY/4zQCteguuUkMoII64N/O/QaKGLd@xyp8NwOhAUNJOnjXWak@dKwERRbak@B3ea2P5Zmte/8A)

### Explanation

```
y/(),/<>'/                   # Replace parens and commas with brackets and apostrophes
:
  s/([^<>']+)'/,\1 /.          # Remove each apostrophe and insert comma after <
  t                            # Branch to : if substitution was made
  s/ ?<(,+)([^>]+)>/((\1)\2)/  # Change <,,,...> to ((,,,)...)
  t                            # Branch to : if substitution was made
s/^.|(\)) |.$/\1/g           # Remove outermost ()s and extra spaces
```

Comment: This fails on some more complicated cases: `((1,(2,3)),4,(5,6))` and `(1,(2,3),4)`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Good catch. I'll take a look after breakfast.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 75 bytes

```
f=a=>`(${t=a.map(x=>'')})${a.map(v=>t=1/v?1/t?' '+v:v:`(${f(v)})`).join``}`
```

Input array of number|array, output string.

Thanks to Neil, save 2 bytes

Comment: `(1/t?' ':0)+v` can be `1/t?' '+v:v`.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 94 bytes

```
{"(",","&/@Most@#,")",c=1>0;(xIf[j=ListQ@x,c=j;"("<>#0@x<>")",If[c,c=j;x," "<>x]])/@#}<>""&
```

Contains an unprintable `U+F4A1`, a builtin `Function` function.

Takes a `List` of integer `String`s. If this is not allowed, this can be fixed by adding 10 more bytes (this version takes a `List` of `List`s/`Integer`s):

```
{"(",","&/@Most@#,")",c=1>0;(xIf[j=ListQ@x,c=j;"("<>#0@x<>")",If[c,c=j;""," "]<>ToString@x])/@#}<>""&
```

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>88</s> 84 bytes

```
f=a=>a.reduce((s,e)=>s+=e[0]?`(${f(e)})`:/\)$/.test(s)?e:' '+e,`(${[...a].fill``})`)
```

Takes an array of integers and arrays. Edit: Saved 1 byte by using `s+=` instead of two separate uses of `s+`. Saved a further 3 bytes now that I can simplify the inner ternary. If I steal @tsh's ideas then I can get it down to 76 bytes:

```
f=a=>a.reduce((s,e)=>s+=t=1/e?1/t?' '+e:e:`(${f(e)})`,`(${t=a.map(_=>``)})`)
```

Comment: `Your program should take either a tuple or a string representing a sugary tuple` I'd presume that an array of arrays/integers should be fine.

Comment: Sure that is allowed

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 45 bytes

```
{Y"()"b:yJ',X#a-1Fcab.:c>0?s.cyJ(fc)bR") "')}
```

This is a function that takes a list as an argument. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@J9m9b86UklDUynJqtJLXSdCOVHX0C05MUnPKtnOwL5YL7nSSyMtWTMpSElTQUlds/Z/gEaaQrShgpGCsYJJrCYXmBttaKBgaBirYGgEEzFUiAaqiEVWAhEBCilEmyqYxQIlSv8DAA)

#### Commented version

```
; Define an anonymous function (the argument is available inside as the variable a)
{
  ; Yank the string "()" into y variable
  Y "()"
  ; Create a string of len(a)-1 commas, join y on it, and assign to b
  b: y J ',X#a-1
  ; For each item c in a
  F c a
    ; Concatenate to b the following expression
    b .:
      ; Is c integer or list?
      ; (If c is a positive integer, c>0 is true; but if c is a list, c>0 is false)
      c>0 ?
        ; If c is integer, concatenate space followed by c
        s.c
        ; If c is list, call function recursively on c and use the result to join y
        yJ(fc)
  ; Replace ") " with ")" in b and return the resulting string
  b R ") " ')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## R, 316 bytes?

(Have to head out and not sure the proper way to count bytes... plus it's not a great solution but wanted to post it since I spent the time making it...)

```
p=function(x){
x=eval(parse(text=gsub("\\(","list(",x)))
f=function(j,r=T){
p=paste
s=if(r){"("}else{"(("}
o=paste0(s,p(rep(",",length(j)-1),collapse=""),")")
n=lengths(j)
for(i in seq_along(n)){
v=j[[i]]
if(n[i]>1){v=f(v,F)}
o=p(o,v)}
if(!r){o=p(o,")")}
o=gsub(" *([()]) *","\\1",o)
return(o)}
f(x)
}
```

Test cases:

```
> p("(1,2)")
[1] "(,)1 2"
> p("(1,2,3)")
[1] "(,,)1 2 3"
> p("((1,2),3)")
[1] "(,)((,)1 2)3"
> p("(1,2,3,4)")
[1] "(,,,)1 2 3 4"
> p("(1,(2,3))")
[1] "(,)1((,)2 3)"
> p("(10,1)")
[1] "(,)10 1"
```

Comment: It's 301 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVBBTsQwDLznFSUne2UkCkcUjryAW1uhsnJKVlESkrSqVO3bi0sPnDzyzHgmyfuejJ3DtboYYMVNrYaX0UMac2GovFYzlfkLdN@DJu1dqTJXRFT233ijbD7EnEwaS2VVjLOQcdOg7@wLCxCk4kk/QaEEmdNxkTyHqX7DDR9bpGv0fkyFjdZIGjWqYE5BEYWyMYNrXGgK/3yOPoYJAkruYm5d54ZBSWwQ8NbithgLC73jXyxEWgQJ/SC1zsVx/iDP9zUX6AAHbC5Squ9bTRFV5jrnAFF0Vn5H3XfpDC3BM72g2F/3Xw "R – Try It Online")

Comment: [Golfed to 261 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY7BasMwEETv/gpVp9mwgbjtseqxX5Cb7YMbpFRGlVTJNgE33@7KMXRh2X3MMLtpjeLtKFYz@ctog8eNFqP@aeCkzrREFfs86sorp/11/MoYqHIqT9/wvzVVYddPkNZIJJaQpSGJI5KOG7E71sSX4Fwfs1ayaJIkVSYkWGG9yPoHjmiZ1dA0tusqa@DL8l7TrAxm/njcQeCZ7pv4lGjnR841T5@Q4oAG1JE4lJNtW0sOxWyg594h9ilrjGq3tu32lrN5LPNGpe5r@RQ145lfaMvcsRC/Flz/AA "R – Try It Online").

I'd leave an explanation for what I changed, but ironically, I *also* have to go...But +1, I couldn't wrap my head around this at all; nice work!

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 72 bytes

```
f=(a,b="",c="")=>a.map?b+"("+a.map(x=>'')+")"+a.map(x=>f(x,"(",")"))+c:a
```

Input: Array containing numbers and/or arrays

Output:string

Usage: f([...])

Completes all test cases, improvements welcome

Answer (score 0):

## C, 308 or 339 bytes

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#define p putchar
f(s,e,c,i,l)char*s,*e,*c;{i=1,l=40;if(*s++==l){p(l);for(c=s;i;i+=*c==l,i-=*c==41,i+*c==45&&p(44),c++);p(41);}for(;s<e;s=c){for(i=0;isdigit(*s);s+=*s==44)for(i&&p(32),i=1;isdigit(*s);s++)p(*s);*s==l&&p(l);for(c=s,i=1;++c,c<=e&&i;i+=*c==l)i-=*c==41;f(s,c-1);*s==l&&p(41);}}
#define g(x) f(x, x+strlen(x))
```

308 or 339 bytes, depending on whether or not passing a pointer to the end of the input string is allowed; the last line is only there to allow passing a string literal directly without having to calculate its length.

### Explanation

A pretty simple algorithm. It counts the number of commas at the current depth, prints them as a tuple constructor, then follows up with the tuple's arguments, escaped (spaces between numbers, nested tuples between parenthesis), recursively.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
typedef enum { false, true } bool;

void tup2ptsfree(char *s, char *e)
{
  int depth;
  char *c;

  if (*s++ == '(') { /* If we are at the start of a tuple, write tuple function `(,,,)` (Otherwise, we are at a closing bracket or a comma) */
    putchar('(');
    /* do the search for comma's */
    c=s; /* probe without moving the original pointer */
    for (depth=1; depth != 0; c++) {
      if (*c == '(') depth++;
      if (*c == ')') depth--;
      if (*c == ',' && depth == 1) putchar(','); /* We have found a comma at the right depth, print it */
    }
    putchar(')');
  }
  while (s < e) { /* The last character is always ')', we can ignore it and save a character. */
    bool wroteNumber;
    for (wroteNumber=false; isdigit(*s); wroteNumber = true) {
      if (wroteNumber) p(' ');           /* If this is not the first number we are writing, add a space */
      while (isdigit(*s)) putchar(*s++); /* Prints the entire number */
      if (*s == ',') s++;                /* We found a ',' instead of a ')', so there might be more numbers following */
    }
    /* Add escaping parenthesis if we are expanding a tuple (Using a small if statement instead of a large branch to prevent doing the same thing twice, since the rest of the code is essentially the same for both cases). */
    if (*s == '(') putchar('(');
    /* Find a matching ')'... */
    c=s+1;
    for (depth=1; c <= e && depth != 0; c++) {
      if (*c == '(') depth++;
      if (*c == ')') depth--;
    }
    /* Found one */
    /* Note how we are looking for a matching paren twice, with slightly different parameters. */
    /* I couldn't find a way to golf this duplication away, though it might be possible. */
    /* Expand the rest of the tuple */
    tup2ptsfree(s, c-1);
    /* idem */
    if (*s == '(') putchar(')');
    /* Make the end of the last expansion the new start pointer. */
    s=c;
  }
}

#define h(x) tup2ptsfree(x, x+strlen(x))
```

### Test cases and application

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAYSIZE(arr) (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr))
static char *examples[] = {
  "(1,2)",
  "(10,1)",
  "(1,2,3)",
  "(1,2,3,4)",
  "((1,2),3)",
  "(1,(2,3))",
  "(1,(2,3),4)",
  "((1,2),(3,4))",
  "((1,(2,3)),4,(5,6))",
  "((1,((2,3), 4)),5,(6,7))",
  "(42,48)",
  "(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)"
};

int main(void)
{
  int i;
  for (i=0; i < ARRAYSIZE(examples); i++) {
    printf("%-32s | \"", examples[i]);
    g(examples[i]); /* Test with golfed version */
    printf("\"\n");
    printf("%-32s | \"", examples[i]);
    h(examples[i]); /* Test with original version */
    printf("\"\n");
  }
}
```