# Elixir Array Syntactic Sugar

Tags: code-golf, string, parsing

In Elixir, (linked) lists are in the format `[head | tail]` where **head** can be anything and **tail** is a list of the rest of the list, and `[]` - the empty list - is the only exception to this.

Lists can also be written like `[1, 2, 3]` which is equivalent to `[1 | [2 | [3 | []]]]`

Your task is to convert a list as described. The input will always be a valid list (in Elixir) containing only numbers matching the regex `\[(\d+(, ?\d+)*)?\]`. You may take the input with (one space after each comma) or without spaces. The output may be with (one space before and after each `|`) or without spaces.

For inputs with leading zeroes you may output either without the zeroes or with.

Input must be taken as a string (if writing a function), as does output.

### Examples

```
[] -> []
[5] -> [5 | []]
[1, 7] -> [1 | [7 | []]]
[4, 4, 4] -> [4 | [4 | [4 | []]]]
[10, 333] -> [10 | [333 | []]]
```

[related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/126410/sugar-free-syntax), not a duplicate as this in part involves adding mode `]` to the end. Additionally, the Haskell answer here is quite different to the one there.

Comment: -1 from me. [Cumbersome IO formats](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/76162) are discouraged. If the input is a  list, let us take it as a list instead of having 90% of our code just parsing the input

Comment: [*very* similar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/126410/sugar-free-syntax), but I wouldn't quite call it a dupe.

Comment: @JoKing Discouraged, not banned :)

Comment: Do we have to support leading 0s? They fit the regex.

Comment: Why does the output need a space before *and* after a `|` (if we include spaces)? Elixer seems to parse any number of spaces, including none

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sugar Free Syntax](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/126410/sugar-free-syntax)

Comment: @JoKing I'd argue that here the challenge itself is about converting between two specific formats, so parsing the input is a fundamental part of the challenge and not something extra added to it. P.S. I've realized only now what your nickname really is xD

Comment: Why do we want to take input as string , and same for output. That is 14 bytes worth in JavaScript just converting back and forth.

Comment: @MuhammadSalman: the challenge is tagged as "parsing", so converting from/to a string is a substantial part of it with intent.

Answer (score 9):

### Haskell, 50 bytes

```
f.read
f(a:b)='[':show(a+0)++'|':f b++"]"
f _="[]"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JclLDoMgEADQvaeYzAYIaPrdkHAET0CJGa2gES2RJt307KVpunmbN1FexhhLMLfim32ke@U56V4YZpnO0@PFSR6ElOzNtIdeSnRYeegMWodlpXkDAyultgOe9nl7NkGA/aVCe/yrTuqsLurq0JXP4COFXOohpS8)

The `+0` lets the Haskell type checker know that we are dealing with lists of numbers, so `read` will parse the input string for us.

Comment: +1, I love the +0 trick!

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 50 bytes

```python
r='%s'
for x in input():r%='[%s|%%s]'%x
print r%[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfnJ@SaqukpPS/yFZdtVidKy2/SKFCITMPiApKSzQ0rYpUbdWjVYtrVFWLY9VVK7gKijLzShSKVKNj/wO1cXGlVqQmK4BM0TL9Hx3LFW0KxIY6CuZAykRHAYRAAgY6CsbGxrEA)

Comment: So beautiful ;-;

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 50 bytes

```javascript
s=>eval(s).map(v=>`[${p+=']',v}|`,p='[]').join``+p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/Y1i61LDFHo1hTLzexQKPM1i4hWqW6QNtWPVZdp6y2JkGnwFY9OlZdUy8rPzMvIUG74H9yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahlJ0rJKmJhe6oClWUUMdBXOsEiY6CiCEXZOBjoKxsTFI7j8A)

---

## Recursive version, 51 bytes

```javascript
f=(s,[v,...a]=eval(s))=>1/v?`[${v}|${f(s,a)}]`:'[]'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVajWCe6TEdPTy8x1ja1LDFHo1hT09bOUL/MPiFapbqstkalOg2oJlGzNjbBSj06Vv1/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoZSdKySpiYXuqApVlFDHQVzrBImOgoghF2TgY6CsbExSO4/AA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>39</s> <s>33</s> <s>32</s> 20 bytes

```
\b]
,]
+`,(.*)
|[$1]
```

Saved 13 bytes thanks to H.PWiz, ovs, ASCII-only, and Neil.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/PyYplksnlks7QUdDT0uTqyZaxTD2//9oEx0gjOWKjgUA)

#### Explanation

```
\b]
,]
```

If we don't have an empty list, add a trailing comma.

```
+`,(.*)
|[$1]
```

While there are commas, wrap things with `|[ thing ]`.

Comment: @ovs [24?](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/P5ZLJ5YrJlqHK5pLO0FHQ09Lk6smWsUw9v//aBMdIIzlio4FAA)

Comment: [also 24?](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/XyMmRTOWS8VQJ5ZLO0FHQ09Lk6smWsUw9v//aBMdIIzlio4FAA)

Comment: @ASCII-only You can save another 4 bytes by replacing `\b]` with `,]`. (Otherwise I had independently discovered the same solution.)

Comment: Oh, that's right. I forgot `\b` was a thing for some reason >_> [20 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/PyYplksnlks7QUdDT0uTqyZaxTD2//9oEx0gjOWKjgUA) @Mnemonic

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pl`, <s>31</s> 28 bytes

```perl
s/\d\K]/,]/;$\=']'x s/,/|[/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YPyYlxjtWXydW31olxlY9Vr1CoVhfR78mWj/9//9oYx2j2H/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULcv7r@prqGRgaAAA)

## How?

```perl
-p                    # (command line) Implicit input/output via $_ and $\
s/\d\K]/,]/;          # insert a comma at the end if the list is not empty
$\=']'x s/,/|[/g      # At the end of the run, output as many ']' as there are
                      # commas in the input.  Replace the commas with "|["
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), <s>111</s> 85 bytes

```
f=fn[h|t],f->"[#{h}|#{f.(t,f)}]"
[],_->"[]"
h,f->f.(elem(Code.eval_string(h),0),f)end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83JrMgs@v8/zTYtLzqjpiRWJ03XTilauTqjtka5Ok1Po0QnTbM2VokrOlYnHiQDZGaA1AClUnNSczWc81NS9VLLEnPii0uKMvPSNTI0dQw0gZpS81L@e/rrFZSWFCsAFStFm@gogFCsElCSC0XG0EBHwdjYGIsMWOg/AA)

I have never used Elixir before. Defines a function that takes a string and a reference to itself and returns a string.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ceylon](https://ceylon-lang.org), 113 bytes

```ceylon
String p(String s)=>s.split(" ,[]".contains).select((x)=>!x.empty).reversed.fold("[]")((t,h)=>"[``h`` | ``t``]");
```

[Try it online!](https://try.ceylon-lang.org/?gist=e3d815b7459bfe561287963eea4aaef5)

Here is it written out:

```ceylon
// define a function p mapping Strings to Strings.
String p(String s) =>
    // we split the string at all characters which are brackets, comma or space.
    s.split(" ,[]".contains)    // → {String+}, e.g.  { "", "1", "7", "" }
    // That iterable contains empty strings, so let's remove them.
    // Using `select` instead of `filter` makes the result a sequential instead of
    // an Iterable.
     .select((x)=>!x.empty)    // → [String*], e.g.   [1, 7]
    // now invert the order.
    // (This needs a Sequential (or at least a List) instead of an Iterable.)
     .reversed                 // → [String*], e.g.   [7, 1]
    // Now iterate over the list, starting with "[]", and apply a function
    // to each element with the intermediate result.
     .fold("[]")                       // → String(String(String, String))
    //    This function takes the intermediate result `t` (for tail) and an element
    //    `h` (for head), and puts them together into brackets, with a " | " in the
    //    middle. This uses String interpolation, I could have used `"+` and `+"`
    //    instead for the same length.
          ((t,h)=>"[``h`` | ``t``]");  // → String
```

[Try it online!](https://try.ceylon-lang.org/?gist=60089c0d591e519aa80079ae130ca435)

As noted by ovs in a (now deleted) comment: If one select the "without spaces" options for input and output indicated in the question, one can safe 3 more bytes (the obvious ones with spaces in them).

If we don't need to parse the input, but just could get a sequence as input, it gets much shorter (69 bytes).

```ceylon
String p(Object[]s)=>s.reversed.fold("[]")((t,h)=>"[``h`` | ``t``]");
```

[Try it online!](https://try.ceylon-lang.org/?gist=6235914fe86ec21c8ce1c327022165b0)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 65 bytes

```python
lambda k:"["+''.join(f"{u}|["for u in eval(k))+-~len(eval(k))*"]"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHbSilaSVtdXS8rPzNPI02purS2JlopLb9IoVQhM08htSwxRyNbU1Nbty4nNU8DxtVSilX6X1CUmVeikaahFG2iA4WxSpqa/wE)

If the input could be a list instead, then:

**[Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 53 bytes**

```python
lambda k:"["+''.join(f"{u}|["for u in k)+-~len(k)*"]"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHbSilaSVtdXS8rPzNPI02purS2JlopLb9IoVQhM08hW1Nbty4nNU8jW1NLKVbpf0FRZl6JRppGtIkOFMZqav4HAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 114 bytes

```
	I =INPUT
S	N =N + 1	
	I SPAN(1234567890) . L REM . I	:F(O)
	O =O '[' L ' | '	:(S)
O	OUTPUT =O '[' DUPL(']',N)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYw9C4MwFADnl1/xtpfQUIzaLyFDQQsB@xKMmcSlc6lD1/73mKXTwR3c97O9tnebMzi0jkOaRQRGy3hAA6LYGO4sTd20p/PleqsUHnHEaXgWOuge0isBHq1HWqgUwh8SdDIq4cGnuRz/sU9hlLSSZiUG7nNejDa1btYd)

```
	I =INPUT				;* read input
S	N =N + 1				;* counter for number of elements (including empty list)
	I SPAN(1234567890) . L REM . I	:F(O)	;* get value matching \d until none left
	O =O '[' L ' | '	:(S)		;* build output string
O	OUTPUT =O '[' DUPL(']',N)		;* print O concatenated with a '[' and N copies of ']'
END
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```
'[,1;@j,]';#$&." |",,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9Xj9YxtHbI0olVt1ZWUdNTUqhR0tH5/z/aREcBhGIB)

If there weren't weird restrictions on output, we could do this in 18:

```
'[,1;@j,]';#$&.'|,
```

Fun fact, this is technically a program that does nothing in Python.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
É▲²:WlÖ└%ï╪☺╒▓"We↨Φ
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=901efd3a576c99c0258bd801d5b222576517e8&i=[1,+2,+3]&a=1)

My first Stax post, so probably not optimal.

Unpacked and commented:

```
U,                      Put -1 under input
  {                     Block
   i                      Push loop index, needed later
    '[a$'|++              Wrap the element in "[...|"
            m           Map
             '[+        Add another "["
                s2+     Get the latest loop index + 2
                   ']*+ Add that many "]"
```

[Run and debug this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=U,+++++++++++++++++++++%09Put+-1+under+input%0A++%7B++++++++++++++++++++%09Block%0A+++i+++++++++++++++++++%09++Push+loop+index,+needed+later%0A++++%27[a%24%27%7C%2B%2B+++++++++++%09++Wrap+the+element+in+%22[...%7C%22%0A++++++++++++m++++++++++%09Map%0A+++++++++++++%27[%2B+++++++%09Add+another+%22[%22%0A++++++++++++++++s2%2B++++%09Get+the+latest+loop+index+%2B+2%0A+++++++++++++++++++%27]*%2B%09Add+that+many+%22]%22&i=[1,+2,+3])

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 22 bytes

```
+:'[J"|[":msr¹₁*₁Lr
"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X9tKPdpLqSZaySq3uOjQzkdNjVpA7FPEpRT7//9/pWhDAx1jY@NYJQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-p`, 39 bytes

Full program:

```ruby
$_[$&]="|[#$2]"while/(,|\d\K(?=]))(.*)/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/XyU@WkUt1lapJlpZxShWqTwjMydVX0OnJiYlxlvD3jZWU1NDT0tT////6FiuaFMgNtQxB5ImOkAI4hnoGBsbx/7LLyjJzM8r/q9bAAA)

#### [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>48</s> 45 bytes

Recursive function:

```ruby
f=->s{(s[/,|\d\K(?=])/]&&="|[")&&f[s+=?]]||s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxNCoMwEIX3PUVIISiN1RDFVfQAPcI4i/6FLksTF8Xx7GmCNDLw4H3f8D7z7RuCNdXglsJBLWl6TJdiNFjWKIThBLwUwoI7mRGRyK0BDhyQyyOrBgYYS5dbxyiixJTsM1WJ9ptKrpXxsm2T2AO3H9VIrfU@0SQXyX8Fz8/r/bWQp/fsHbPgcQ0/)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>84</s> <s>71</s> 69 bytes

```r
function(x){while(x<(x=sub('(,|\\d\\K(?=]))(.+)','|[\\2]',x,,T)))1;x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NCs7o8IzMnVaPCRqPCtrg0SUNdQ6cmJiYlJsZbw942VlNTQ09bU11HvSY6JsYoVl2nQkcnRFNT09C6ovZ/moZSdKySJheINoUxDHXMYUwTHSCEixvoGBsbA3n/AQ)

- -15 bytes thanks to @KirillL.

Comment: [71 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NCs7o8IzMnVaPCRqPCtrg0SUNdQ6dGw97GNiYmRVPD3jZWU1NDT1tTXUe9JjomxihWXadCRydEU1PT0Lqi9n@ahlJ0rJImF4g2hTEMdcxhTBMdIISLG@gYGxsDef8B) with a single substitution based on my Ruby answer.

Comment: @KirillL. : thanks, I was sure there was a shorter regex to do that, but I always mess up with lookarounds :D

Comment: [-2 more](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NCs7o8IzMnVaPCRqPCtrg0SUNdQ6cmJiYlJsZbw942VlNTQ09bU11HvSY6JsYoVl2nQkcnRFNT09C6ovZ/moZSdKySJheINoUxDHXMYUwTHSCEixvoGBsbA3n/AQ), I totally forgot about a shorter `\K` lookbehind

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 bytes

```
ŒVḢ,ŒṘÇ”|;ƲƊ¹¡⁾[]j
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATYAyf9qZWxsef//xZJW4biiLMWS4bmYw4figJ18O8ayxorCucKh4oG@W11q////J1sxMCwgMzMzXSc)

Answer (score 1):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 57 bytes

```
k=>"["+''.join(str(u)+"|["for u:(e=eval(k)))+-~len(e)*"]"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcKxCoAgEADQX4lbvMtqagrsR8Sh4QRTVEybol@3Jd7LJdUUu1Xdqx00SCGWM7mIVy3YSMKjwaYytA1Z8X0E9EQk5zdwRKYRDPRcXKxoEfQ6/QwQ9Q8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 19 bytes

```
ŒV©;€⁾|[”[;µ®L‘”]ẋṭ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AToAxf9qZWxsef//xZJWwqk74oKs4oG@fFvigJ1bO8K1wq5M4oCY4oCdXeG6i@G5rf///ydbMTAsIDMzM10n)

A non-recursive alternative to [Erik's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163849/59487).

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒVµ⁾[]jj⁾|[ṫ3;”]ṁ$
```

A full program printing the result (as a monadic link it accepts a list of characters but returns a list of characters and integers).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opLBDWx817ouOzcoCUjXRD3euNrZ@1DA39uHORpX///@rRxsa6CgYGxvHqgMA)**

#### How?

```
ŒVµ⁾[]jj⁾|[ṫ3;”]ṁ$ - Main link: list of characters  e.g. "[10,333]"
ŒV                 - evaluate as Python code              [10,333]
  µ                - start a new monadic chain, call that X
   ⁾[]             - list of characters                   ['[',']']
      j            - join with X                          ['[',10,333,']']
        ⁾|[        - list of characters                   ['|','[']
       j           - join                                 ['[','|','[',10,'|','[',333,'|','[',']']
           ṫ3      - tail from index three                ['[',10,'|','[',333,'|','[',']']
                 $ - last two links as a monad (f(X)):
              ”]   -   character                          ']'
                ṁ  -   mould like X                       [']',']'] (here 2 because X is 2 long)
             ;     - concatenate                          ['[',10,'|','[',333,'|','[',']',']',']']
                   - implicit (and smashing) print        [10|[333|[]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Standard ML](http://www.mlton.org/), 71 bytes

```ml
fun p[_]="]|[]]"|p(#","::r)="|["^p r^"]"|p(d::r)=str d^p r;p o explode;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HchLCsMgEADQfU8xTDcJWGixq4gnkTEUjBAwOhgTuvDu5rN7vHUJryWUFFvzWwQ2I2mkaoiwcvdEgcOQe43VoGXIFu93d64lg7tWMSSY/hySm1TbfwE8aJiLelweT3OeY@k8oPm8hZRSfAn7dgA) Uses the format without spaces. E.g. `it "[10,333,4]"` yields `"[10|[333|[4]|[]]]]"`.

**ungolfed**

```ml
fun p [_]       = "]|[]]"          (* if there is only one char left we are at the end *)
  | p (#","::r) = "|[" ^ p r ^ "]" (* a ',' in the input is replaced by "|[" and an closing "]" is added to the end *)
  | p (d::r)    = str d ^ p r      (* all other chars (the digits and the initial '[') are converted to a string and concatenated to recursive result *)

val f = p o explode  (* convert string into list of chars and apply function p *)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYtBCsMgFET3nmL43SRgocWuAj2J/IaCEQpGxdjShXe3mtBZzOK9mW1159Xl4Gu1b48IPTOO3EFcNDNBAKWp4USSpimNXRVNeDSYWhPTf2J2v7@3nGCOjRCfp4NtMCJg@UYXzFI7mztLL58HC9LXi1RKyRvTWH8)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 10, 107 bytes

```java
s->{var r="[]";for(var i:s.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]","").split(","))r="["+i+"|"+r+"]";return s.length()<3?s:r;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jY9BTsMwEEX3PcXIK1txLSAgpKYFcQC6YZlmYVy3uHWdaOxEQiVnDxOIWKLIY2nG/vP1/kl3ennanwfjdYzwql24LgBcSBYP2ljYjiPAW0IXjmD41ERR0HtPlyomnZyBLQTYwBCXT9dOI@CGlRUrDjXycXSrqNA2nkxfvOes3O2oqopJxoSKjXeJUy/EuMcyl7EvlmHGyAJtajFAVN6GY/rgYp0/xxUW/VD8AjTtuyeAiaOr3R4ulGSCLSstphSfMdmLqtukGvpJPvCgDB85xU@gfyQPMzS38nGW6k7mM3T3ks4MuxuZ539@/aIfvgE)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->{                       // Method with String as both parameter and return-type
  var r="[]";              //  Result-String, starting at "[]"
  for(var i:s.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]","") 
                           //  Removing trailing "[" and leading "]"
             .split(","))  //  Loop over the items
    r="["+i+"|"+r+"]";     //   Create the result-String `r`
  return s.length()<3?     //  If the input was "[]"
          s                //   Return the input as result
         :                 //  Else:
          r;}              //   Return `r` as result
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>140</s> 136 bytes

Down 4 bytes as per Giuseppe's sound advice.

```r
function(l,x=unlist(strsplit(substr(l,2,nchar(l)-1),", ")))paste(c("[",paste0(c(x,"]"),collapse=" | ["),rep("]",length(x))),collapse="")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxBC8IwDIXv/oqQUwMZbE7x4n7J8FBL5walK2sLPfjfayZMhEC@l5f3tjrdmzplb9KyeuW4DNm7JSYV0xaDWwTyU1isM3szayFqOmJkQCIKOiarjMIR@cutiML4QGKzOqdDtAPCG0Y5bDYocdhZ/0qzKpL/e0Kqk/RI8rTv6wEdw@3gC8M@P6tl6PteZP0A)

Comment: `substr` is shorter and the first `paste0` can be `paste` to get this to 136 bytes.

Comment: Using `eval`, `parse`, and `sub` instead of `unlist`, `strsplit` and `substr`, I also only managed 136 bytes (I thought it might be shorter but it wasn't)

Comment: @Giuseppe Thanks for the -4 bytes! I wish we had something shorter. Recursive solution maybe?

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 108 bytes

```r
function(l)Reduce(function(x,y)paste0("[",x,"|",y,"]"),eval(parse(t=sub("]",")",sub("\\[","c(",l)))),"[]",T)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYpNCsIwEIX3niLMagaeUIniRi9R3LUuYkxBCLU0ibTg3WMqtMOD@d7PmDt12ecu9Ta@3j17qd0zWcdbMmGWwYToKqaGMIG@hBl0J4H7GM@DGYPjeA3pwSUFCeHPbVv2ZJngpRyoKe1NcscLyW75pxUOUOeVj1CLtqqC0loXm38)

It took almost a year to find a better R solution than previous...should have known `Reduce` would be the answer! Outputs without spaces, input can be with or without spaces.

Comment: [102 using strsplit instead of eval+parse](https://tio.run/##PYlBCsIwFET3niL8Tf6HESpV3HgKcddkoTWVQqilSaCF3j2aRQsD897MlDt1O@YuDW3svwN7ubt3ah3vy4xFxmeIrmJqCDNoJSwgSwLnOcQpjL6P/AnpxdqYZjXGamgNL9BQWgTUWMJDcseF5FD6ssEJ6rrxGapkvyqouq7/mn8 "R – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 63 bytes

```python
lambda s:'['+'|['.join(map(str,eval(s))+[']'])+']'*len(eval(s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU7dCoIwFL6upzh3Z8shmoogrBdZu1ilZMw5dAWB724by4LDd873w8exb3cfzXHt@HnVarjcFMwNCkxwEZg@xt6QQVkyu4m1L6XJTGkiUKKkiceDbg3Z9LUbJ@iNZTA@nfUXCIFCIoOAkoFnVaQVLCDkJuYM6qjnQa@jubklgzAxUAbvD/IfyzMGRVF8e7Lgevqrks1@Z6feuPgh8pMPdsQTum3Ow9/p1Fqtri1BQIZI1w8)

Answer (score 0):

## sed + `-E`, 46 bytes

```
:
s/\[([0-9]+)(, ?([^]]*)|())\]/[\1 | [\3]]/
t
```

A fairly straightforward approach. The second line takes `[\d+, ...]` and changes it to `[\d | [...]]`. The third line jumps back to the first line, if the substitution was successful. The substitution repeats until it fails and then the program terminates. Run with `sed -E -f filename.sed`, passing input via stdin.

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 110 bytes

```
func[s][if s ="[]"[return s]replace append/dup replace/all b: copy s",""|[""]"(length? b)- length? s"]""|[]]"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3BCsIwEETv/YplTwqRKlGEgvgPXsMe0mSjhZCGpDkI/nuMoEiZy7yZgUls642tos4N1ZVgVCY1OchwQUWoEi8lBciUOHptGHSMHGxvS4Rv1GvvYRzAzPEJGQXiSyESbjyH@/K4wrjdwc/nVrSeCKnGNIUFHHyOuj@cVnQQ5xUfRdN6sRdSSsL6Bg)

### Explanation of the ungolfed version:

```
f: func[s][                      
    if s = "[]" [return s]                    ; if the list is empty, return it    
    b: copy s                                 ; save a copy of the input in b 
    replace/all b "," "|["                    ; replace every "," with "|["  
    append/dup b "]" (length? b) - length? s  ; append as many "]" as there were ","
    replace b "]" "|[]]"                      ; replace the first "]" with "|[]]"     
]                                             ; the last value is returned implicitly
```

[Red](http://www.red-lang.org) is so easily readable, that I doubt I needed adding the above comments :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 38 bytes

```perl6
{'['~S:g/\s|.<($/\|\[/~']'x$_+1}o&EVAL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/Wj1avS7YKl0/prhGz0ZDRT@mJiZav049Vr1CJV7bsDZfzTXM0ee/NVdxYqVCmoJStKGOkY5xrBJCwBSZY6hjjsyNVfoPAA)